# Best way to save multiple collections under one user UID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing an app where there is not a lot of interaction with other users. Set and retrieve your own data only.

In Firebase Firestore how could I model this so that everything fits under a users UID?

Something that would look like this?

```
users/{uid}/user/
users/{uid}/settings/
users/{uid}/weather/
```

If I want to achieve something like this, then I need to create another UID:

`users/{uid}/user/{uid}/{userInfo}`

This feels a bit off to me.

1. Is this wrong? Would it be better if I moved every subcollection into its own collection?
2. Is this faster / more efficient?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The most common approaches for me:

0. Store the profile information, settings and weather in the user document (your `{uid}`) itself. This most common for the profile information, but it's always worth considering for other types too: do they really need to be in their own documents?
1. Have a default name for a single subcollection for each user, and then have each information type as a document with a known name in there. So `/users/$uid/documents/profile`, `/users/$uid/documents/settings`, and `/users/$uid/documents/weather`. So now each information type is in a separate document, meaning you can for example secure access to them individually.
2. If the information for a certain type is repeated, I'd put that in documents in a known/named subcollection. So if there are many weathers, you'd get `/users/$uid/weather/$weatherdocs`. So with this you can now have an endless set of the specific type of information.

Neither of these is pertinently better/worse, as it all depends on the use-cases of your app.

There will be performance differences between these approaches, as they require a different number of network requests. If this is a concern for your app, I'd recommend testing all approaches above to measure their relative performance against your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Frank! I am going for option 0 (1). I will save each category within ONE document as "an object of objects".  `{ weather: {}, settings: {} }` because there won't be a use case where they will be queried independently.